# How do I display Django model choice list in a template?

Tags: python, django

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find the answer for this problem I'm having and was wondering if anyone would be kind enough to help.

I am trying to display the choices itself (Q_TYPE) as a list of radio buttons in a template. I've tried "get_FOO_display", but it seems that it only displays something if attached to another value.

Below is my best attempt out of many and what I am looking for. If anyone could help me with the problem I would really appreciate it. Even the keywords I should be looking for I would appreciate. Thanks!

Models.py

```
Q_TYPE = (
('T', 'Text Question'),
('M', 'Multiple Choice'),
)

class Question(models.Model):
   form = models.ForeignKey(Form)
   textquestion = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
   questiontype = models.CharField(('question type'), max_length=1, choices=Q_TYPE)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.textquestion
```

Template

```
{% for questiontype in q_type %}
    {{ questiontype }} <input type="radio" name="{{ questiontype }}" id="" value="" /><br />
{% endfor %}
```

What I'm trying to get (< > is a radio button)

```
 < > Text Question
 < > Multiple Choice
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using a form?  It'll do this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm pretty new to Django and I'm trying to have the forms be able to be customized. Not sure if forms can do this, but if they do thanks for the info. Regardless if someone could answer the question above for my own knowledge I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass in the `Q_TYPE` into your template context, and the do:

#### views.py

```
context = {'Q_TYPE': Q_TYPE}
return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

#### template

```
{% for id, value in Q_TYPE %}
    {{ value }} <input type="radio" name="{{ id }}" id="" value="" /><br />
{% endfor %}
```

or use indexing on the loop variable

```
{% for item in Q_TYPE %}
    {{ item.1 }} <input type="radio" name="{{ item.0 }}" id="" value="" /><br />
{% endfor %}
```

but, as I mentioned in my comment, you should be trying to use the built in `ModelForm` system.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just curious though, is ModelForm flexible enough to make a form be able to be customized/edited by the user? If so, I'd definitely switch over.

Comment: Yup, you can do a lot of customization.  I very rarely have to resort to straight html.

Comment: Yeah no problem.  Checkout the widget customization.. Chances are if you create once, you'll (or someone else if you open source it) eventually need to use a similar idiom later on.

Comment: Just for clarification, by "user customization" I meant eventually having the website allow third party users to edit form labels/fields beings able to be created/edited/added/deleted. 

Is the ModelForm system able to do that? I took a brief view at it and it seems to be only admin/developer server side use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```py
# models.py
class Subscription(models.Model):
    UNSUB = "UNSUB"
    OK = "OK"
    EXPIRED = "EXPD"
    _STATUS_LABELS = [
        (UNSUB, "Unsubscribed"),
        (OK, "Ok"),
        (EXPIRED, "Expired"),
    ]
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=_STATUS_LABELS,
        default=UNSUB,
    )


# views.py
def demo(requests):
    status_labels = Subscription._STATUS_LABELS
    return render(request, 'pandora/course.html', locals())


# demo.tpl
{% for value in status_labels %}
<p>{{ value.0 }}:{{ value.1 }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```